# Почему устойчивое вульгарное словосочетание "до фига" не может быть эвфемизмом?

Tags: жаргонизмы

Помогите мне, пожалуйста, определиться с ответом на вопрос: почему устойчивый *фразеологизм* "до фига" не может быть *эвфемизмом*?

Мне сказали так:

> Для особо одаренных, повторяю, что
> словосочетание "до фига" в принципе не
> является эвфемизмом, поскольку не
> является завуалированным
> представлением созвучного понятия из
> ненормативной лексики, а является
> самостоятельным общепринятым
> словосочетанием".

Я понимаю так, что эвфемизмом для иносказания,в принципе, может быть любое подходящее словосочетание. Или нет? Устойчивое не может?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Не совсем понял логику. Есть предположение, что она отсутствует. "Фиг" можно заменить на что покрепче. Я предпочитаю последовательность неприличности *фиг→хрен→жопа→хер→ӾⓨŇ*: фиг может использовать девочка-отличница из третьего класса, на последнее же слово, сказанное не тому человеку и не в той ситуации реакция может быть бурной.

Далее, широко известно, что "до Ӿⓨ*i*Я" — тоже устойчивое сочетание, и "до фига" успешно его заменяет и наоборот. Откуда у людей сведения, что оно является самостоятельным и независимым сочетанием? Естественно, его уровень приличия позволяет сочетанию использоваться широким кругом лиц (в том числе очень приличных) в самых разных ситуациях. Но это ведь и является эфвемизмом? Думаю, если этот вопрос нужно раз и навсегда выяснить, спорами профанов на форуме обойтись не удастся: нужно привлекать литературу разных веков и научно выяснить происхождение выражений. Тогда и может оказаться, что они независимы (но верится слабо). Совсем нейтральным и не эвфемизмом может оказаться выражение "до чёртиков": оно даже по употребимости в сочетаниях не совсем соответствует оригиналу.

Вот "хрень" мне нравится своей самостоятельностью, потому что структурно отличается от ряда *фигня...x&%ня*.

Comment: Тогда уж _совсем_ не эвфемизмом является слово "очень":) Сохранение грамматической конструкции всё равно наводит на мысли об эвфемистичности.

Comment: На мой слух в русском нормально сказать "Ты меня до чёртиков напугал". Ни один из эвфемизмов с "до" сюда вставить нельзя: они обычно означают "очень много", а не "очень сильно".

Comment: Уважаемая Shady_arc, спасибо Вам (и всем откликнувшимся) за помощь!
 Ваше аргументированное мнение мне очень помогло.
Сердечное Вам спасибо.

Comment: Думаю,  что  хрень  от  фигни  мало  чем  отличается.

Comment: Я имел в виду структурно. Не секрет, что тем и удобна морфология: можно в слове, скажем, оӾⓨŇэнный заменить корень на "хер", и получить новое слово, уже не настолько неприличное. Всё ещё перебор? А вот хрен! Вставьте его. Даже "хрен" не годится? Говорите "офигенный". Ну а если даже так слишком ругательное, можно уж сказать "восхитительный" или "замечательный".

Answer (score 1):

Я присоединюсь. Вполне может. Другое дело, что исходное выражение само по себе - идиома. Вот не знаю, как смотрит классическая лингвистика на такой вариант. Ну и еще то, что тут непонятно, что первично, что чем заменяют. Других причин отказывать "в до фига" быть эвфемизмом я не вижу.

[[@Валz](/users/3944/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BBz)](/users/3944/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BBz), А если не секрет, как вы определили, что Shady_arc - уважаемая? А не уважаемый?

Comment: не знаю, родился я мальчиком. А там посмотрим. Будущее иногда так непредсказуемо. :)

Comment: По  аватарке,  наверное.  Картинка  маленькая,  можно  и  ошибиться.